# How to find out colour of placeholder?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to set colour of placeholder, but what if I need to find out what's colour of placeholder on some page? I cannot find this property with Chrome Devtools. ColorZilla doesn't help either.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It will only be defined in the CSS file I suspect, it's not an html element or pseudo-element so it can't be found with the web inspector.

Comment: Web inspector like Chrome DevTools or Firebug etc? I cound't find it with these inspectors. There is no rule with word 'placeholder' among other css-rules

Comment: The easiest solution is to just install a color picker extension in chrome and then hover over the colour with your tool to get the hex and rgba code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't access the pseudo `placeholder` attribute's CSS in DevTools. You can only get the text value using `getAttribute('placeholder')` in JavaScript.

However, it is possible to view the style properties using JavaScript instead of manually finding them in the CSS files. This is not ideal, but I created a general purpose function that allows you to specify the selector (or part of the selector), and the attribute you are looking for, and it will loop through all the stylesheets and log a table to the console.

```
function getSelectorStyle(selector, attribute) {

    var rules = [];

    function CSSRule(sheet, selector, value) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
        this.selector = selector;
        this.value = value;
    }

    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var currentSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        if (currentSheet != null) {
            var ruleList = currentSheet.cssRules;
            if (ruleList != null) {
                for (var j = 0; j < ruleList.length; j++) {
                    var currentRule = ruleList[j];
                    if (currentRule.selectorText != null) {
                        if (currentRule.selectorText.indexOf(selector) != -1) {
                            var sheetLocation = currentSheet.href ? currentSheet.href : "inline-css";
                            var item = new CSSRule(sheetLocation, currentRule.selectorText, currentRule.style[attribute]);
                            rules.push(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.table(rules)
}

getSelectorStyle("placeholder", "color");
```

[image: Example]

### Update:

In terms of your problem with the colour not matching with the Amazon site, as per the comments below, it appears that the selector `.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder` is not applied. The `input` field isn't contained in `form-control`. The default placeholder colour is applied instead, which is `#A9A9A9` (in Chrome at least), which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way excluding using JavaScript for those, who haven't started to study JS yet? :)

Comment: Not that I know of, unless there's a Chrome Extension that effectively does this. However, you don't need to worry about understanding the code too much. You just need to run the code in the Console on your page (e.g. using a Snippet in DevTools) and then you can execute it in the console using getSelectorStyle("placeholder", "color");. This will log out all the selectors, which contain 'placeholder' in them, and the associated 'color' value. I could look into creating an extension to hide the implementation details at some point.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But there's one problem: function has returned the color, but it doesn't match - it more dark

Comment: @AleksandrMikheev There may be a CSS `filter` property changing the computed value maybe? Are you able to provide a link or snippet I can test with?

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/newsroom/index.html? There is search form in the top-right corner

Comment: @AleksandrMikheev It looks right to me. `rgb(119,119,119)` matches the `#777` HEX value in the stylesheet. See [color-hex](http://www.color-hex.com/color/777777).

Comment: I mean when I try to make same form and apply rgb(119,119,119) to placeholder it appears to be remarkably darker :(

Comment: @AleksandrMikheev I have added an update to the answer, as it appears after all of this, the placeholder selector isn't applied and the actual colour is the default one for the browser. See details in the update above.

Comment: Thank you! #A9A9A9 is what I needed) Anyway you function is very helpful, thank you for that too